# scala Unspecified Value Parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to extend the SparkSession class in spark. I copied the constructor of the original SparkSession partially reproduced here:

```
class SparkSession private(
    @transient val sparkContext: SparkContext,
    @transient private val existingSharedState: Option[SharedState],
    @transient private val parentSessionState: Option[SessionState],
    @transient private[sql] val extensions: SparkSessionExtensions)
  extends Serializable with Closeable with Logging { self =>

  private[sql] def this(sc: SparkContext) {
    this(sc, None, None, new SparkSessionExtensions)
  }

  // other implementations

}
```

Here's my attempt at extending it:

```
class CustomSparkSession private(
    @transient override val sparkContext: SparkContext,
    @transient private val existingSharedState: Option[SharedState],
    @transient private val parentSessionState: Option[SessionState],
    @transient override private[sql] val extensions: SparkSessionExtensions)
  extends SparkSession {

  // implementation

}
```

But I get an error on the `SparkSession` part of `extends SparkSession` with error:

> Unspecified value parameters: sc: SparkContext

I know that it's coming from the `this` constructor in the original SparkContext, but I'm not sure how, or if I can even extend this properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Why exactly you want to extend the `SparkSession`? If you want to add some helper methods you may create an implicit wrapper.

Answer (score 14):

When you write `class Foo extends Bar` you are actually (1) creating a default (no-argument) constructor for class `Foo`, and (2) calling a default constructor of class `Bar`.

Consequently, if you have something like class `Bar(bar: String)`, you can't just write `class Foo extends Bar`, because there is no default constructor to call, you need to pass a parameter for `bar`. So, you could write something like

```
class Foo(bar: String) extends Bar(bar)
```

This is why you are seeing this error - you are trying to call a constructor for `SparkSession`, but not passing any value for `sc`.

But you have a bigger problem. That `private` keyword you see next to `SparkSession` (and another one before `this`) means that the constructor is ... well ... private. You cannot call it. In other words, this class cannot be subclassed (outside the `sql` package), so you should look for another way to achieve what you are trying to do.